# CakePHP: Error when set Configure::write('Session.timeout', 0 )

Tags: session, cakephp

I use both version on windows and ubuntu. I met this error on both.
This is error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcpFk.png.

I can reproduce this error when set Session.timeout = 0 (Session must save database ) then refresh page 2 times and report to CakePHP LightHouse but MarkStory don't happen as same .

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1173-cakesession-circular-dependancy-race-condition-or-infinite-loop

I will very happy if anyone can fix this matter O_O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, i found out this matter ^^. If you save session in database and Configure::write('Session.timeout', '0'); and most important, set public $cacheQueries = true; in 'app\app_model.php'. Refresh browser 2 times ,error happen.